# How many verbal forms are there in Spanish? // ¿Cuántas formas verbales hay en español?

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales, preguntas-canónicas

> This is a [canonical question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) / Esta es una [pregunta canónica](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674)

It turns out that I am learning English and I have doubts about the verbal forms of that language, but seeing this I realized that I am not clear about those of Spanish either.

Does anyone know how many and what are the verbal forms in Spanish and (if any) its equivalent in English?

---

Resulta que estoy aprendiendo inglés y tengo dudas con las formas verbales de ese idioma, pero viendo esto me di cuenta de que tampoco tengo claras las del español.

¿Alguien sabe cuántas y cuáles son las formas verbales que hay en el español y (si las hay) su equivalente en inglés?

Comment: [Aquí](http://es.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080407160654AAp3KtE#yui_3_9_1_9_1393815807025_581) puedes ver un buen resumen de las formas **verbales**

Comment: 1. Cuantas formas hay en inglés es off-topic aquí. 2. Cuando dices "formas verbales", ¿a qué refieres? tiempos verbales?

Comment: Los tiempos verbales en español se refieren las confluencia de diversa categoría gramaticales como tiempo gramatical y espeto gramatical‚ que en una lengua función ante aparece funcionados en los mofermaflexivos del verbo.

Comment: Es dificil definir 'equivalentes' porque depende del contexto etc. pero hay un resumen bueno aquí https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verb-forms.htm Por lo general, los verbos ingleses tienen pocos cambios de deletreo comparado con español y el modo subjuntivo casi no se usa (británico), sin embargo hay más palabras auxiliares como do/could/would/should que no tienen equivalente en el español.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aquí tienes la conjugación del verbo cantar tal como me la enseñaron en el colegio:

## Modo indicativo

### Presente

```
cant-o
cant-as
cant-a
cant-amos
cant-áis
cant-an
```

### Pretérito imperfecto

```
cant-aba
cant-abas
cant-aba
cant-ábamos
cant-abais
cant-aban
```

### Pretérito

```
cant-é
cant-aste
cant-ó
cant-amos
cant-asteis
cant-aron
```

### Pretérito perfecto

```
he     cantado
has    cantado
ha     cantado
hemos  cantado
habéis cantado
han    cantado
```

### Pretérito pluscuamperfecto

```
había    cantado
habías   cantado
había    cantado
habíamos cantado
habíais  cantado
habían   cantado
```

### Pretérito anterior

```
hube      cantado
hubiste   cantado
hubo      cantado
hubimos   cantado
hubisteis cantado
hubieron  cantado
```

### Futuro

```
cant-aré
cant-arás
cant-ará
cant-aremos
cant-aréis
cant-arán
```

### Futuro perfecto

```
habré    cantado
habrás   cantado
habrá    cantado
habremos cantado
habréis  cantado
habrán   cantado
```

### Condicional

```
cant-aría
cant-arías
cant-aría
cant-aríamos
cant-aríais
cant-arían
```

### Condicional perfecto

```
habría    cantado
habrías   cantado
habría    cantado
habríamos cantado
habríais  cantado
habrían   cantado
```

## Modo subjuntivo

### Presente

```
cant-e
cant-es
cant-e
cant-emos
cant-éis
cant-en
```

### Pretérito

```
cant-ara    o cant-ase
cant-aras   o cant-ases
cant-ara    o cant-ase
cant-áramos o cant-ásemos
cant-arais  o cant-aseis
cant-aran   o cant-asen
```

### Futuro

```
cant-are
cant-ares
cant-are
cant-áremos
cant-areis
cant-aren
```

### Pretérito perfecto

```
haya    cantado
hayas   cantado
haya    cantado
hayamos cantado
hayáis  cantado
hayan   cantado
```

### Pretérito pluscuamperfecto

```
hubiera    o hubiese    cantado
hubieras   o hubieses   cantado
hubiera    o hubiese    cantado
hubiéramos o hubiésemos cantado
hubierais  o hubieseis  cantado
hubieran   o hubiesen   cantado
```

### Futuro perfecto

```
hubiere    cantado
hubieres   cantado
hubiere    cantado
hubiéremos cantado
hubiereis  cantado
hubieren   cantado
```

## Imperativo

```
cant-a  (tú)
cant-e  (usted)
cant-ad (vosotros)
cant-en (ustedes)
```

Answer (score 7):

En español hay **22** formas verbales:

[image: formas verbales en tabla]

(Par ver la tabla con snippet: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332560/335589.)

- 5 **no personales** (por carecer de marcas que señalen persona gramatical) y
- 17 **personales** (aquellas cuyas desinencias indican la persona gramatical, además del modo, el tiempo y el número).

## Formas no personales: 5 = 2 inf. + 1 part. + 2 ger.

- Infinitivo: simple (*amar*) y compuesto (*haber amado*).
- Participio: *amado*.
- Gerundio: simple (*amando*) y compuesto (*habiendo amado*).

## Formas personales: 17 = 10 ind. + 6 subj. + 1 imp.

- ### Modo indicativo: 10 = 5 simp. + 5 comp.

  - #### 5 tiempos simples

    - Presente: *amas* / *amás*.
    - Pret. imperfecto / copretérito: *amabas*.
    - Pret. perfecto simple / pretérito: *amaste*.
    - Futuro simple / futuro: *amarás*.
    - Condicional simple / pospretérito: *amarías*.
  - #### 5 tiempos compuestos

    - Pret. perfecto compuesto / antepresente: *has amado*.
    - Pret. pluscuamperfecto / antecopretérito: *habías amado*.
    - Pret. anterior / antepretérito: *hubiste amado*.
    - Futuro compuesto / antefuturo: *habrás amado*.
    - Condicional compuesto / antepospretérito: *habrías amado*.
- ### Modo subjuntivo: 6 = 3 simp. + 3 comp.

  - #### 3 tiempos simples

    - Presente: *ames*.
    - Pret. imperfecto / pretérito: *amaras* o *amases*.
    - Futuro simple / futuro: *amares*.
  - #### 3 tiempos compuestos

    - Pret. perfecto compuesto / antepresente: *hayas amado*.
    - Pret. pluscuamperfecto / antepretérito: *hubieras* o *hubieses amado*.
    - Futuro compuesto / antefuturo: *hubieres amado*.
- ### Modo imperativo: 1

  - *ama* / *amá*.

Notas:

1. He utilizado la segunda persona del singular para poder indicar la forma de voseo, cuando existe, separada por una barra y porque el imperativo solo tiene segunda persona.
2. Solo he utilizado un verbo, *amar*, como muestra de la forma; es el que usa la RAE como modelo de la 1ª conjugación.

---

We have **22** verbal forms in Spanish:

- 5 **impersonal** forms (for they lack grammatical person markers) and
- 17 **personal** forms (those whose desinences show the grammatical person, besides mood, tense and number).

## Impersonal or non-finite forms: 5 = 2 inf. + 1 part. + 2 ger.

- Infinitive: simple (*amar*) and compound (*haber amado*).
- Past participle: *amado*.
- Gerund: simple (*amando*) and compound (*habiendo amado*).

## Personal forms: 17 = 10 ind. + 6 subj. + 1 imp.

- ### Realis or indicative mood: 10 = 5 simp. + 5 comp.

  - #### 5 simple tenses

    - Presente (present): *amas* / *amás*.
    - Pret. imperfecto / copretérito (imperfect): *amabas*.
    - Pret. perfecto simple / pretérito (preterite): *amaste*.
    - Futuro simple / futuro (future): *amarás*.
    - Condicional simple / pospretérito (conditional): *amarías*.
  - #### 5 compound tenses

    - Pret. perfecto compuesto / antepresente (present perfect): *has amado*.
    - Pret. pluscuamperfecto / antecopretérito (past perfect or pluperfec): *habías amado*.
    - Pret. anterior / antepretérito (past anterior): *hubiste amado*.
    - Futuro compuesto / antefuturo (future perfect): *habrás amado*.
    - Condicional compuesto / antepospretérito (conditional perfect or compound conditional): *habrías amado*.
- ### Subjunctive mood: 6 = 3 simp. + 3 comp.

  - #### 3 simple tenses

    - Presente (present subj.): *ames*.
    - Pret. imperfecto / pretérito (imperfect sub.): *amaras* o *amases*.
    - Futuro simple / futuro (future subj.): *amares*.
  - #### 3 compound tenses

    - Pret. perfecto compuesto / antepresente (present perfect subj.): *hayas amado*.
    - Pret. pluscuamperfecto / antepretérito (pluperfect subj.): *hubieras* o *hubieses amado*.
    - Futuro compuesto / antefuturo (future perfect subj.): *hubieres amado*.
- ### Imperative mood: 1

  - *ama* / *amá*.

Notes:

1. I used second-person singular to point out the voseo form, when different,  separated by a slash and because the imperative only has the second person.
2. I used a single verb, *amar*, to show the form; it's used by the RAE as the first conjugation model.

Comment: Para una explicación exhaustiva de este tema / Further reading v. [Modelos de conjugación verbal](https://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/modelos-de-conjugacion-verbal).

Comment: Wow!...........

Comment: Well thank you. After trying table replacements finally I quit and made a list... at least for now.

Comment: The formatting came out well, I think.  Yes, sometimes it's frustrating not to be able to make a simple table....

Comment: @aparente001 He añadido la versión española en forma de tabla referenciando mi respuesta a la pregunta de las tablas en meta. A ver qué te parece. Si estuvieran activos los snippets se podría poner aquí.

Answer (score 6):

Agrego las conjugaciones del Voseo (Hablar de Argentina, Uruguay, Paraguay, Centroamérica (desde Chiapas México hasta partes Colombia) y pequeñas zonas en otros países hispanohablantes. Si la conjugación viene después de la diagonal es exclusivo de centroamérica.

## Modo indicativo

### Presente

```
cant-ás
```

### Pretérito imperfecto

```
cant-abas
```

### Pretérito

```
cant-aste
```

### Pretérito perfecto

```
has cantado
```

### Pretérito pluscuamperfecto

```
habías cantado
```

### Pretérito anterior

```
hubiste cantado
```

### Futuro

```
cant-arás
```

### Futuro perfecto

```
habrás cantado
```

### Condicional

```
cant-arías
```

### Condicional perfecto

```
habrías cantado
```

## Modo subjuntivo

### Presente

```
cant-es/cant-és
```

### Pretérito

```
cant-aras o cant-ases
```

### Futuro

```
cant-ares
```

### Pretérito perfecto

```
hayas cantado
```

### Pretérito pluscuamperfecto

```
hubieras o hubieses cantado
```

### Futuro perfecto

```
hubieres cantado
```

## Imperativo

### Positivo

```
cant-á
```

## Imperativo

### Negativo

```
no cant-es/no cant-és
```

## Indicativo

### Pretérito anterior

```
hubiste cantado
```

Comment: Después de la diagonal?

Comment: check http://www.verbix.com/