# ¿Vosotros se emplea como tú?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, ustedeo

Si alguien pregunta a otra persona "*¿Hablasteis con él?*" Podría pensar que más de una persona habló con él. Sin embargo, me he dado cuenta que es propio de la variante ibérica emplear la conjugación de la segunda persona del plural para expresar una acción en singular.

Por qué no "¿Hablaste con él?"
¿Tiene sentido esto que pregunto?
¿Cómo se le llama a esto?

Comment: Mm nunca he oído eso en España. Lo que sí ocurre mucho es el uso de la forma incorrecta "*hablastes con él". Es posible que sea eso lo que has oído?

Comment: Eso, y falta documentación. Quién te lo dijo? Cómo? Cuándo? Dónde? En qué contexto? Información adicional que considere útil?

Answer (score 2):

Puede ser un [plural mayestático](https://blog.lengua-e.com/2011/plural-mayestatico/), usado cuando el hablante se dirige a un rey o a un papa, o cuando estos se refieren a sí mismos. En la actualidad solo se usa en situaciones muy formales, como en actos protocolarios que involucran a un rey.

Otra opción es la que comenta @wimi, que en realidad diga *hablastes*, forma incorrecta relativamente habitual de *hablaste*, y que cualquier corrector ortográfico intentará desesperadamente sustituir por *hablaste* o *hablasteis*.

Answer (score 2):

Puede depender de variantes regionales. En España por ejemplo, donde hay por supuesto *tuteo* y *ustedeo* pero no es frecuente el *voseo*, al decir "*¿Hablasteis con él?*" entenderíamos que se refiere a una conjugación del verbo en plural.

Creo que sería conveniente revisar preguntas existentes, como

- [What is the etymology of the pronoun “usted”? What formal pronouns existed before?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/251/5481)
- [Why is “Usted” grammatically a third person?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/836/5481)

que puede darte una idea de dónde procede la forma "usted" y porqué es una tercera persona. Puede que así sea más fácil entender que prácticamente la única manera de usar "Hablasteis" como una conjugación en segunda persona singular es con una suerte de *arcaísmo*, tipo

> "¿Hablasteis con él, majestad?"

> "¿Hablasteis con él, señoría?"

Nadie usaría esta forma de esa manera hoy en día (de nuevo, las preguntas enlazadas pueden ayudarte a entender esto, así como las explicaciones en las otras respuestas sobre que esto es usado "usado cuando el hablante se dirige a un rey o a un papa").

Es muy difícil generalizar sobre los países hispanoamericanos, debido a las preferencias regionales del ustedeo el voseo y las variante del voseo. Como norma general, me atrevería a decir (ya me corregirán los usuarios que son nativos de esos países), que allí se favorecerían formas como

> ¿Habló (usted) con él? / ¿Hablaron (ustedes) con él?

para la segunda persona del singular y plural respectivamente, allí donde se suele usar más el ustedeo.

Dado lo variado del voseo (en Argentina: hablás, en Chile: hablaí) no me sorprendería que en algún sitio se pudiese usar "Hablasteis" para una segunda persona del plural, pero tampoco me sorprendería lo contrario ("Habló vos con él").

Por norma general creo que la conjugación "hablasteis" se referirá a un plural y no al singular.

Answer (score 0):

No, **vosotros** no se emplea como segunda persona singular.
**Hablasteis** corresponde a segunda persona del singular porque el pronombre elidido es **vos**.

**Vos** efectivamente es segunda persona singular, y es una forma en desuso en la península Ibérica, pero que en algunos países de América se ha mantenido, aunque ha evolucionado a otros registros. Es decir, el registro original de **vos** era formal, en Argentina y otros países es coloquial, aunque puede que en Argentina ya lo consideren formal.

Bueno, en Chile al menos, es considerado vulgar (cómo pasó de formal a vulgar es tema de otra pregunta), y si, la conjugación informal que se hace en Chile vine del voceo:

Antiguo *vos sois*, *vos estáis*, *vos hablasteis*

Actual (vulgar): *voh soi*, *voh ehtai*, *voh hablahte*

*La h es para graficar la s aspirada. Nótese que en *hablaste* se hace la conjugación como si fuera precedida del pronombre tu.

Answer (score 0):

This can be explained as an example of over-generalization. This phenomenon often occurs in children's language acquisition where they learn a rule but then apply it too widely. If we look at the complete conjugation of the Spanish verb, for example in this canonical question [How many verbal forms are there in Spanish? // ¿Cuántas formas verbales hay en español?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5180/how-many-verbal-forms-are-there-in-spanish-cu%c3%a1ntas-formas-verbales-hay-en-e) we see that in every tense apart from the preterite the second person singular familiar form ends in the letter *s*. It is not too surprising that people erroneously put and *s* on the end of *hablaste*.

As a personal anecdote for many years I thought the preterite second person singular familiar of *ganar* was *ganastes* having misunderstood that the speaker was actually asking *¿Ganasteis?* and talking to both the people not just one.